# selecting average response times from two database tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL - `tickets` and `ticket_updates`

With the following structure:

`tickets`

- sequence
- ticketnumber
- datetime

`ticket_updates`

- sequence
- ticketnumber
- datetime

the relationship is: `tickets.ticketnumber = ticket_updates.ticketnumber`

i want to find out the Average response time for a certain day based on when rows are inserted into `ticket_updates`

I tried this Query:

```
SELECT avg(response_seconds) as s FROM 
    (SELECT time_to_sec(timediff(min(u.datetime), u.datetime)) AS response_seconds 
    FROM tickets t JOIN ticket_updates u ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber 
    WHERE u.type = 'update' and t.customer = 'Y' and DATE(u.datetime) = '2016-04-18' 
    GROUP BY t.ticketnumber) 
    AS r
```

but everytime, its returning `0.000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with:

```
(SELECT time_to_sec(timediff(min(u.datetime), u.datetime)) AS response_seconds
```

which returns 0 on my console. Try with:

```
( select time_to_sec( timediff( from_unixtime( floor( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(u.datetime)/60 )*60 ), u.datetime) ) ) as response_seconds;
```

like

```
SELECT avg(response_seconds) as s FROM 
    ( select time_to_sec( timediff( from_unixtime( floor( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(u.datetime)/60 )*60 ), u.datetime) ) ) as response_seconds 
    FROM tickets t JOIN ticket_updates u ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber 
    WHERE u.type = 'update' and t.customer = 'Y' and DATE(u.datetime) = '2016-04-18' 
    GROUP BY t.ticketnumber) 
    AS r
```

Comment: thats now just returning `NULL`

Comment: Yeah, on my machine also returns NULL, I totally rewrote my answer, with a different solution

Comment: thats returning a syntax error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tickets t JOIN ticket_updates u ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber WHE' at line 3`