# cannot find SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to run this SQL Query:

```
SELECT avg(response_seconds) as s FROM 
    ( select time_to_sec( timediff( from_unixtime( floor( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(u.datetime)/60 )*60 ), u.datetime) ) ) as response_seconds 
    FROM tickets t JOIN ticket_updates u ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber 
    WHERE u.type = 'update' and t.customer = 'Y' and DATE(u.datetime) = '2016-04-18' 
    GROUP BY t.ticketnumber) 
    AS r
```

but i am seeing this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tickets t JOIN ticket_updates u ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber WHE' at line 3
```

and i cannot work out where the error is in the query

Comment: What SQL?  SQL Server?  Update your tags.

Comment: edited question :)

Comment: Looks like you closed `)` too early before `as response_seconds`. That belongs inside the `(select...)` but you have it outside.  The `correct syntax to use near FROM` means you must look immediately before that to find the issue.

Comment: You have 2 `FROM`s - One from the nested query and the second from tickets, you need to `JOIN tickets` to the query

Comment: my original question was here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694833/selecting-average-response-times-from-two-database-tables but i wasnt getting a response

Comment: I think your parens are unbalanced, particularly looking at the three closing parens at the end of the code/query fragment where the error is being reported. I think you have one too many )'s there, and the query parser throws its hands up in surrender... :)

Comment: You have 6 opening `(`, which should be finally closed after `GROUP BY`, but the 6th closing `)` occurs just before `as response_seconds` instead.

Comment: You should format your query and use a decent editor which will show you pairs of brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`)` the one more extra parenthesis in the `) ) as response_seconds` causing the problem, removing that will solve the problem. For better readability I aligned the code:

```
SELECT avg(response_seconds) AS s 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
        time_to_sec( 
            timediff( 
                from_unixtime( 
                    floor( 
                            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(u.datetime)/60 
                        )*60 
                ), u.datetime
            )   -- ) the one more extra parenthesis causing the problem
        ) as response_seconds 
    FROM tickets t 
    JOIN ticket_updates u ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber 
    WHERE u.type = 'update' and t.customer = 'Y' and DATE(u.datetime) = '2016-04-18' 
    GROUP BY t.ticketnumber
) AS r
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `)` just before `as response_seconds`

```
SELECT avg(response_seconds) as s FROM 
    ( select time_to_sec( timediff( from_unixtime( floor( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(u.datetime)/60 )*60 ), u.datetime) ) as response_seconds 
      FROM tickets t 
         JOIN ticket_updates u ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber 
      WHERE u.type = 'update' 
        and t.customer = 'Y' 
        and DATE(u.datetime) = '2016-04-18' 
      GROUP BY t.ticketnumber
    ) AS r
```

You had to many closing brackets on that calculation which had the effect of closing the sub select to early.

Comment: But then you have `FROM response_seconds` and `FROM tickets`?

Comment: Its a sub query, it need a FROM

Comment: Oh, now after the aligning, I see you're correct. +1

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an extra ')' here "tetime) ) ) <-- as response_seco"

```
SELECT avg(response_seconds) as s
FROM (
      select time_to_sec( timediff( from_unixtime( floor( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(u.datetime)/60 )*60 ), u.datetime) ) as response_seconds 
      FROM tickets t JOIN ticket_updates u ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber 
      WHERE u.type = 'update' and t.customer = 'Y' and DATE(u.datetime) = '2016-04-18' 
      GROUP BY t.ticketnumber
    ) AS r
```

Answer (score -1):

Count your parentheses.  You're essentially doing this:

```
SELECT some_column as s
FROM some_sub_select as response_seconds 
FROM tickets t JOIN ticket_updates u ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber 
....
```

You can't have two `FROM` clauses in the same query.

Maybe you have mis-aligned parentheses?  Maybe you meant to do a `JOIN` instead of a second `FROM`?  It's difficult to tell from what appears to be an incomplete overall query.